# Postgres Docker - unable to connect from remote server

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I am using postgres:9.5.3 docker image. I am starting the containers and then trying to connect to the psql database from a remote host but each time it fails with the error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "172.18.0.2" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In my docker-compose file, I am mounting the pg_hba.conf. This is my docker-compose file:

```
services:
    db:
      networks:
        - test
      image: postgres:9.5.3
      expose:
        - 5432
      volumes:
        - ./pgdata/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./pg_hba.conf/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

I have modified my pg_hba.conf file to accept remote connections from all hosts based on the instructions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). My pg_hba.conf is as follows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::0/0                   trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

And my postgresql.conf has the following line too: `listen_addresses = '*'`

When I try to connect to the database from the host I am running the container on, it connects successfully. But when I try to connect from any remote machine using the command `psql -h 172.18.0.2 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432`, it gives me the connection error that means remote connections are not working. With all these settings, I would expect it to connect. What am I missing here?

Comment: "172.18.0.2" Is 172.0.0.0/8  bridged / routed / firewalled ? IIRC there is something special about 172. networks.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem like you are actually publishing the exposed port.

instead of:

```
expose:
  - 5432
```

use:

```
ports:
 - "5432:5432"
```

`expose` docs:

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll
>   only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be
>   specified.