# Rselenuim/Docker - unable to connect to remote server for firefox

Tags: r, rselenium, docker-selenium

My Rselenium suddenly stopped. I looked for answers, tried all of them without any luck.I then uninstalled docker and reinstalled, restarted my machine and all of that. Finally have managed to get a piece of code working, so I know my machine is not broken.

The code that is working for me is:

```
library(RSelenium)

# Specify the port
port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))

# opens a new browser
cDrv3<- rsDriver(port = port,browser = "firefox",chromever = NULL, )

remDr <- cDrv3[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com")
remDr$getTitle()
remDr$closeWindow()
```

However, this code is too cumbersome in that it downloads the browser every time and open a new browser. This makes it slow and inefficient.

What I want is to make this code work:

```
system("docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest") # this part works.
remDr <<- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",  browserName = "firefox", port = 4445)
remDr$open(silent = FALSE)
```

Currently when I run `remDr$open(silent = FALSE)` I get the following error:

```
remDr$open(silent = FALSE)
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 5411 after 2260 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I have tried all of the advise on

[Postgres Docker - unable to connect from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881282/postgres-docker-unable-to-connect-from-remote-server)

[can't execute rsDriver (connection refused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused)

[R Rselenium ".... Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893474/r-rselenium-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-4444-connection-refused)

[RSelenium is not working when creating servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708282/rselenium-is-not-working-when-creating-servers)

Any new ideas to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So after a full day of researching, it appears the problem is within Rselenium. So the work around is to create remote driver in Python and use reticulate to import the function into the existing r code.

Comment: Source of idea is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76430355/web-scraping-with-rselenium-and-docker-standalone-image

Answer (score 1):

RSelenium [does not work with the latest version of Selenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/280). Either:

1. Use an older version of Selenium (e.g. `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-firefox:4.8.3`). You might have to experiment to find a version that RSelenium is compatible with.
2. Use the newer [selenium](https://ashbythorpe.github.io/selenium-r/) package, that works with the latest version of Selenium.